Help Using Cauchy Criterion
Consider the function $g:[0,1] \to \mathbb R$ defined as follows:$$
g(x) = \begin{cases}
k; & x = \frac1k \text{ for some } k \in \mathbb N_+\\
0; & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Use the Cauchy criterion to show that $g$ is not Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$, without using upper and lower Riemann sums, but using signed partitions $P$ and $Q$.

you can modify this solution to get your answer
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4308477/how-to-show-that-a-function-is-not-riemann-integrable-by-using-cauchy-criterion
